# Creating a HTTP connecting and keeping it open to recieve data

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to connect to a server via HTTP and maintain that connection so that the server can periodically send me data. The server will be sending data in json format. The server is a closed system and this is how I've been asked to communicate with it.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Can I use a UrlConnection or maybe Apache's HttpClient to achieve this? Does anyone have any sample codes or articles I could use?

Comment: The HTTP Keep-Alive header is likely what you want.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: HTTP Keep-Alive does not help you with pushing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With traditional HTTP technology you can only do polling, which means you request "do you have more data" from the server. The server than can wait for some time when it has no data (this is called "long polling"). This should be a short time so it works with stuff inbetween which terminate too long http requests. A slightly more complicated version would be to send chunked responses and sent chunks when new data becomes available. In both cases you need to deal with broken conections and re-query.

There are a few frameworks which hides this. Newer technology would use WebSockets, but then client and server must support it.

BTW: normally http client libraries "do keep the connection open", this is called http keep-alive, but this does not directly help you because HTTP always needs an request to answer to.

You did not say what you actually want/need to do. So it is hard to recommend anything. But if you do not know about the specifics of HTTP protocol it is best if you stay away from implementing it yourself.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right, OP probably meant server push.